# How to convert string to date format in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to convert a column in a csv file that contains the following datetime format.

```
12 mar 2016 10:27:47 fm
```

But when I change type to DateTime I get this error:

```
Error: Could not parse the input provided to a DateTime value
```

I have tried converting using different locale as well with no success.

How can I convert it to a correct datetime format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our date/time parser for locales like Swedish where you'd use "fm" for "am" only allows 24-hour time. Sorry that you ran into this!

Alejandro's fix would look like:

```
DateTime.FromText(Text.Replace(Text.Replace("12 mar 2016 10:27:47 fm", " fm", " am"), " em", " pm"))
```

Comment: It is a mix of the US locale date format "12 mar 2016 10:27:47 pm" but with the Swedish abbreviations for both am/pm and the month names. So I had to replace "maj" with "may" and "okt" with "oct" as well. Problem solved! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Should the fm on that line be am or pm?

You can work around it by replacing fm in the text with am or pm using `Text.Replace` and then using that text in `DateTime.FromText`.